# Can some one explain how this code return 4

Tags: php

Please see the below code this is work perfectly in PHP. Can anyone explain me how this code works and why it returning 4.

```
<?php
  error_reporting(0);
  $var_a = '33';
  $var_b = &$var_a;
  $var_c = &$var_b;
  echo $var_c * ( $var_b ="2 + $var_b");
?>
```

This question was a recruitment interview for the php programmer.

Comment: All in all, I'd say this is a very poor question designed to attempt to _trick_ the interviewee into making a mistake

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's beneficial to break it down line-by-line. There's also more information to be found by enabling error reporting, ie `error_reporting(E_ALL)`

1. `$var_a = '33';`

   Easy enough, assign the string `"33"` to `$var_a`.
2. `$var_b = &$var_a;` and `$var_c = &$var_b;`

   Assign both `$var_b` and `$var_c` to the reference address of `$var_a`. See http://php.net/manual/language.references.php. For all intents and purposes, they are the same variable with different names.

For the next line, I'll break it down into parts in order of evaluation

1. `"2 + $var_b"`

   This is a string with the value `"2 + 33"`. The 33 comes from the `$var_a` assignment
2. `$var_b ="2 + $var_b"`

   This assigns the previous string (`"2 + 33"`) to `$var_b` and consequently to `$var_a` and `$var_c`. The return value from an assignment expression is the value assigned.
3. `$var_c * ( $var_b = "2 + $var_b")`

   What you're left with here is something that looks like

   ```
   "2 + 33" * "2 + 33"
   ```

   with error reporting enabled, you get

   > PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in ...

   because this is obviously not a sound mathematical expression. However, PHP is very forgiving and tries its best to evaluate it. What happens is it attempts to parse as much numeric content as possible from each operand which stops at the first space after `"2"` so you're left with

   ```
   "2" * "2"
   ```

   thanks to PHP's loose typing, this evaluates to `4`.

Answer (score 0):

`$var_a` contain the value 33. `$var_b` contain address of `$var_a`, `$var_c` contain address of `$var_b`. so if you assign the value to any variable
then it will change value of all variable. 
 `$var_b ="2 + $var_b"` in This equation you are changing the value 33 of `$var_b` to 2 because you are assigning `"2 + $var_b"`. while assigning value to variable `$var_b`, it will only consider 2. Now value of all variables is 2.
final equation  `$var_c * ( $var_b ="2 + $var_b")` calculate as `2 * 2` return 4

Comment: will you please explain briefly that i didn't understand